# Crosswalk 23 used with Cordova - Huge performance problems

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I've been using Cordova with Crosswalk Webview for more than 2 years. The version I am currently on is Crosswalk version 17 with Chromium 47. I got stuck with this version, as Crosswalk versions 18+ were unable to play mp3 audio's. (issue https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7307)

This has been fixed in Crosswalk 23 running Chromium 53. BUT, I am having horrible performance issues. Crosswalk 17 was running great, very smooth when scrolling, scaling, translating .. but with 23 and Chromium 53, it is almost unusable.

Are you guys experiencing the same issues? Is there anything I can do to fix this? Maybe something change for chromium 47 - 53, maybe a default build flag was changed .. I have tried adding a couple of xwalkCommandLine options, such as `--enable-gpu-rasterization` but that didn't seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you enable hardware acceleration in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I did enable it